# Shopping cart cakephp+bootstrap modal

Tags: cakephp, shopping-cart, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with my shopping cart system using cakephp + bootstrap modal. The problem is that when I click/select one of my images, it will add to the cart but it will always display the last item/data in my database. Even though I'v selected the first item, it will still display the last item/data in my database. Please help me out of this.

CartsController.php

```
class CartsController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('Sidedish','Cart');

public function add() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Cart->addProduct($this->request->data['Cart']['product_id']);
    }
    echo $this->Cart->getCount();
}

public function view() {
    $carts = $this->Cart->readProduct();
    $side_dishes = array();
    if (null!=$carts) {
        foreach ($carts as $productId => $count) {
            $side_dish = $this->Sidedish->read(null,$productId);
            $side_dish['Sidedish']['count'] = $count;
            $side_dishes[]=$side_dish;
        }
    } 
    $this->set(compact('side_dishes'));
            print_r($carts);
            print_r($side_dishes);
}}
```

views/Orders.ctp -> this is where I will need to click the item to display in the cart.

```
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <?php echo $this->Form->create('Cart',array('id'=>'add-form','url'=>array('controller'=>'carts','action'=>'add')));?>
                  <ul class="list-inline">
                      <?php foreach ($side_dish as $sidedish):?>
                      <li>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('product_id',array('value'=>$sidedish['Sidedish']['sidedish_id'])); ?>
                        <?php 
                        echo $this->Form->submit(//$sidedish['Sidedish']['sidedish_id'],
                                '',array(
                'name'=>'submit',
                                    'style'=>'height:130px;width:200px;'
                                    . 'background-repeat:no-repeat;'
                                    . 'border:none;'
                                    . 'background-image:url(/webapp' .$sidedish['Sidedish']['sidedish_img']. ')'));
                        ?>
                        <h5 class="text-center"><?php echo $sidedish['Sidedish']['sidedish_name'];?></h5>
                        <h5 class="text-center">$<?php echo $sidedish['Sidedish']['sidedish_price'];?></h5>
                      </li>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>

              </div>
```

Some people told me that the problem is the foreach loop in my views/orders.ctp and some people told me that the problem is in the controller. I'm not sure where is the problem here. please need help guys.

Comment: the problem is in the view: you are looping trough your product but you're creating a lot of hidden inputs all with the same name `product_id`. When you submit your form each input overwrites the last and at the end just the last one is sent to the action.

Comment: I see. Yeah. I also notice it but I cant think of a simple way to fix it. If you have any idea, can you share it to me, please?

Comment: If you want to send your data using POST you can use `Form->postlink()`. But I would simply use a link instead of a button, sending data via query string.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I will try and hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show your code for this function `$this->Cart->addProduct()`?

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class Cart extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = false; 

    /*
     * add a product to cart
     */
    public function addProduct($productId) {
        $allProducts = $this->readProduct();
        if (null!=$allProducts) {
            if (array_key_exists($productId, $allProducts)) {
                $allProducts[$productId]++;
            } else {
                $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
        }

        $this->saveProduct($allProducts);
    }

    /*
     * get total count of products
     */
    public function getCount() {
        $allProducts = $this->readProduct();

        if (count($allProducts)<1) {
            return 0;
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $count=$count+$product;
        }

        return $count;
    }

    /*
     * save data to session
     */
    public function saveProduct($data) {
        return CakeSession::write('cart',$data);
    }

    /*
     * read cart data from session
     */
    public function readProduct() {
        return CakeSession::read('cart');
    }

}
```